# Significance of the control predictors in a non-significant full-null model comparison (mixed model)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mixed-model, multiple-comparisons, lme4-nlme

**The situation:**

`A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` are fixed effects, and `RandomEffect` is a random effect,   all of which are being use to predict the variable `Response`.

My prediction was that `A` and `B` would show a detectable effect on `Response`, but my analyses showed no such pattern. I assumed `C` and `D` to have some effect, but this was based on scientific reasoning (the topic is understudied). As `C` and `D` were "control" predictors, they were included in both the full and null model.

I am interested in understanding how to obtain appropriate p-values and confidence intervals for variables which were not part of my prediction (`C` and `D`), and how to present my results.

**My analysis:**

I used a model with all possible random slopes and correlations between random slopes and intercepts (see [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3881361) for more information).

**Full model R formula:** (`A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` impact `Response`)

```
full = Response ~ A + B + C + D + (1 + A + B + C + D | RandomEffect)
```

**Null model R formula:** (only `C`, and `D` impact `Response`)

```
null = Response ~ C + D + (1 + A + B + C + D | RandomEffect)
```

**Results:**

The full-reduced model comparison - `anova(null, full, test="Chisq")` - was not significant, i.e. no evidence `A` and `B` impact `Response`. However, `C` and `D` do have a detectable effect. Since there is not much known about `C` and `D`’s effect on `Response`, it would be interesting to discuss it in my paper.

**My questions are...**

1. Even though my full-null model comparison was not significant, is it
   still acceptable to report the coefficients / p-values / confidence
   intervals / etc. for `C` and `D`?
2. If yes, would I use values derived from...

   - a.    The full model
   - b.    The null model
   - c.    A simpler model excluding all aspects of the main
     effects, like:

     - `Response ~ C + D + (1 + C + D | RandomEffect)`
3. If the answer to 2 is b. or c., then would I further test the null/simplified model against another, further simplified, model which excludes `C` and `D`? Would I then need to make a correction for multiple testing?

Comment: You state at the beginning that your goal is to test the effects of A and B, but your questions are all based on analyses that say that A & B have no detectable effect. Could you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: My prediction was that A and B have an effect on Response. My data show that they do not. My assumption was that C and D have an effect on Response, and the data show they do. My questions are about how to report the significance/effect of C and D on Reponse, even though they are not part of my original prediction. Does that clarify the question? Is there something else that needs more explanation? Please let me know and I will try to clarify more. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that helps (and I have submitted edits to clarify your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can report the coefficients, p-values, confidence intervals etc whether significant or not.

2) I would favour using co-efficients from the full model, as you have clear a priori reason to include all the parameters that you did. However, it is not uncommon to present co-efficient estimates from a reduced model with only the significant terms retained.

You can obtain p-values for each term in multiple ways, but one of the most reliable methods for mixed models is a bootstrap-based approach. See Halekoh & Højsgaard 2014 (https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i09) and their associated R package 'pbkrtest', which makes this easy to do. To briefly describe the approach, you construct a series of nested models with individual terms dropped, and you perform a bootstrap-based comparison between each reduced model and the full model to evaluate whether the dropped terms contribute to overall explanatory power. You can then construct a final model with only the significant terms (and the random effect) retained, if you wish.

3) I think the answer to #2 covers this.

Let me know if this addresses your question.